# servlet.service() for servlet dispatcherservlet in context with path threw exception

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring, jpa

Hola comunidad soy nueva en springboot y tengo este problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

modelo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

repositorio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

service
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Por qué `PaisService` implementa `PaisRepository`? Eso no tiene sentido y es la causa del stackoverflow que estás teniendo. Quita el `implements PaisRepository` del  `PaisService`  y marca la interfaz  `PaisRepository` con la anotación `@Repository` para que spring cree un Bean que implemente  `PaisRepository` y pueda ser inyectado en tu servicio.

Comment: Por otro lado, por favor, el código va SIEMPRE a texto, nunca en imágenes. Ten en cuenta esto para tus futuras preguntas. Si yo quiero ahora intentar reproducir tu error en mi máquina para ver si hay más errores, tendría que COPIAR A MANO todo tu código porque lo pusiste en imágenes. Eso limita mucho que recibas ayuda en este sitio, la mayoría no va a tomarse el tiempo de teclear tu código.

Comment: Favor de leer Cómo formular una buena pregunta

Comment: @JaimeMenendez que no lo tenga en cuenta para futuras preguntas, mejor que ya edite la actual :)

Comment: Yulieth: [es.so] te da las herramientas necesarias para compartir tu código _como texto, con formato_. Subir capturas de pantalla de código [es mala idea](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Pulsá en [edit] para corregir tu pregunta.